# Pass array from native to hybrid view

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a iOS Hybrid App using PhoneGap.

**My question**

I am creating one array with data in native code which I want to send to hybrid view.

Here is my code,

**index.html**

```
function myJavascriptFunction (obj){
    var array = new Array();
    array = obj;
    console.log(array);
}
```

**objective.m**

```
{
    array =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"NotificationCalled" object:array];
}
```

How can I pass the data from native to hybrid view?

Comment: You can't do this with `NSNotificationCenter`. You must have to create custom plugins to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Bhumeshwer, can telle me how to do it. i am new to phone gap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please proceed to the following steps

1. Write javascript method to handle json array object.

   ```
   function myJavascriptFunction (obj){ // Process json array object. obj.length will give you length and obj[i] will give you i'th element }
   ```
2. Write objc code to create json string

   ```
   array =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil];
   NSString * jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[ %@ ]",[array componentsJoinedByString:@","]];
   ```
3. Then pass jsonString to javascript

   `[yourwebview  stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myJavascriptFunction(%@);",jsonString ]];`